# MS Access table not sorting by primary key

Tags: microsoft-access, sorting

Environment: MS Office LTSC Pro Plus 2021 under Windows 11 Pro 64.

I have an Access table with 300,000 records and 28 fields, including an autonumber primary key. Yesterday, after adding the 28th field, a `Long text` field, and entering notes there in two records, I noticed that the table is no longer sorting correctly by the key.

I have a backup copy of the file, in which the table (with the first 27 fields) does sort correctly on the key. I ran a query that checks the values of the first 27 fields in all 300,000 records with the contents of the table in the backup, and they all report being identical. So there is no data corruption.

The file has another table with the same number of records, and that table does sort correctly on its key.

I closed the file and reopened it, and the table still sorted incorrectly. Then I removed the primary key, saved the table and closed it, then reopened it and reset the key, and it still did not sort on the key. Finally, I shut down everything and rebooted Windows, which included an update. The table still does not sort correctly

I don't really need the sorting of the table; I can always use a query to sort it if I need that. But sorting on the primary key is a pretty fundamental behavior in any database, so this behavior of not sorting on it is making me nervous.

What can cause this to happen, and what should I do about it?

I suppose I could make a copy of the table and hope it will sort correctly, then discard this one. But if that works, I don't want to just ignore this problem in case it indicates some underlying problem I should pay attention to.

**Update**

I restored the most recent backup of the file and then retraced my steps to get to where I was in the other one, including adding that new field to the table and entering the data in the two records, but also including fixing broken links on linked tables, importing some queries from another file, fixing field names in those queries, and running them.

After doing all of that, I think I'm back to where I was before, except that **the table now sorts correctly on its primary key.**

**New question:** Should I delete this question as most likely being about a fluke? Or is there something useful someone can say about what might have caused the problem of not sorting on the key?

Comment: I'm not a MS Access expert, but in an RDBMS a table is inherently unordered.  The db engine will return results in whichever order it desires without a query that specifically states how to order (ie- an ORDER BY clause in the SQL).  I don't know if Access inherently adds this when viewing a table.  I expect not, though, in which case you would need to view it through a Query that includes the ordering.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong when I said, "sorting on the primary key is a pretty fundamental behavior in any database," and perhaps I should have said "in Access" instead of "in any database." What is certain is that Access always sorts on the primary key -- except in this table after I added that memo field.